# (Blender Eevee 2.9) Soft shadow appear as hard shadow in render

Tags: rendering, eevee-render-engine, shadows

I'm making this animation for someone, and when im rendering, the soft shadows i've set up are appearing as hard shadows in the rendered mode. They look absolutely fine and normal in the viewport mode. Here are the images:

Viewport Render:

[image: Viewport Render:]

Actual Rendered Image:

[image]

You can see how hard the shadow is in the rendered version. I have tried everything i can to fix this. Help would be super appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I got a same problem here using EEVEE. But I realized I had a sunlight hiding in my scene. Somehow I press  <kbd>F12</kbd> to final render the hidden sunlight will show up. So I delete that sun light and everything works fine.

Comment: Thank you for the help! No idea if this was the case but the save file is long gone so i cant tell xD But i'll definietly look out for that if this happens again! ^^